# bash: cd: C:Users****: No such file or directory al abrir Git Bash

Tags: git-bash

Quería poner el siguiente código en git bash:

`echo cd C:/Users/**** >> ~/.bashrc`

pero lo puse de la siguiente manera:

`echo cd C:\Users\**** >> ~/.bashrc`

y ahora siempre al abrir git bash me sale:

`bash: cd: C:Users****: No such file or directory`

¿Cómo hago para quitarlo?

---

muchas gracias pero no funcionó jajaj> al final le pregunté a mi querido amigo chatgpt y me dio el comando exacto EN MI CASO:
nano ~/.bashrc
ahí si fui a la interfaz que me dijiste y pude eliminar las lineas de codigo que tanto me molestaban jaja igualmente, muchísimas gracias!!!

Answer (score 1):

Pon el comando `sudo nano ~/.bashrc`

Esto te abrirá el archivo `.bashrc` en un editor de texto en la consola (que viene instalado por defecto), con permisos de superUsuario.  ( te pedriá la contraseña )

Usa el teclado, y solo el teclado (por que el ratón no funciona ahí) para ir hasta el final del archivo. **(abajo)**

En la última (o una de las últimas líneas) tienes que tienes escrito el `C:\Users****` ... Lo borras y guardas.

Eso es por que el comando que pusiste `echo C:\Users**** >> ~/.bashrc` simplemente lo que hace es ****Escribir** esto en *este archivo***

Escribir (echo)

esto (C:\Users****)

en (>>)

este archivo (~/.bashrc)

Un saludo

Comment: hola broo, muchas gracias pero no funcionó jajaj>
al final le pregunté a mi querido amigo chatgpt y me dio el comando exacto EN MI CASO:
nano ~/.bashrc
ahí si fui a la interfaz que me dijiste y pude eliminar las lineas de codigo que tanto me molestaban jaja
igualmente, muchísimas gracias!!!